# Deleting object from Google App Engine Datastore (Python) and using Memcache

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached, google-cloud-datastore

I am attempting to delete an object from the GAE datastore and then cache the remaining datastore objects with memcache.  The object is being successfully deleted, but for some reason the python log and the memcache are not recognizing that one was deleted.  The Datastore Viewer shows that the object is deleted, but the log says the the length of the items is not changing... also the memcache is just caching all of the items, as if no deletion is happening.  Any advice you can give is much appreciated.

**Python code:**

```
 yesterday = datetime.now()-timedelta(days=1)  # one day ago                
 sessions = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM MentorAvailSessions WHERE created > :1", yesterday).fetch(1000)   #pulling list of all objects
 logging.info('************** len before deleting a session: %s*********' % len(sessions)) # shows a length of 3    

 for session in sessions:
     if (session.session_id == end_session_id) and (session.user == user_info.username):
         session.delete();

 remaining_sessions = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM MentorAvailSessions WHERE created > :1", yesterday).fetch(1000)  #pulling list of just the remaining objects after deleting one
 logging.info('** len of remaining sessions: %s' % len(remaining_sessions))  # still shows a length of 3 after session.delete                       

 memcache.set('mentor_avail_sessions_cache', remaining_sessions, time=50000)      # is caching all three items instead of just the remaining 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to eventual consistency. Queries without an ancestor are not guaranteed to be strongly consistent (the dev server exaggerates this effect to make you aware of it, in production you rarely see inconsistencies).

You should ensure that your query uses an ancestor so that it supplies to an entity group. Alternatively, you could decrement the memcache counter explicitly, rather than refreshing it from a query.

Comment: Thanks Daniel - I am sort of nubie with this, can you give me an example of how to decrement the memcache counter?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass#Client_decr

Comment: Thanks, I read your link, but am still not sure how I would go about specifying how to remove a specific session from the memcache... and the one that needs to be removed may not be the last one added.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood: I thought you were using memcache to keep a count. I must say though that I don't at all understand why you are using memcache to store *all* the sessions. That's what the datastore is for, especially as you say you don't have any way of identifying the cached ones invidually. You shouldn't really be doing this. Note that the `ndb` api manages model caching for you.

Comment: Well, I am using the word "session" but it is really a chat session, not necessarily everyone that is logged in. What I am trying to do is just update this list of people available for chat. So when a session is deleted, a person drops off - so the cache needs to be updated without that person on the available list. (just trying to not to hit the database more than I need to)  - But I got it working-  Daniel's idea about ancestors and eventual consistency was correct.  Explaination: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency